# Visual Studio Code: Failed to evaluate. Reason: Cannot evaluate because the thread is resumed. When trying to use scanner

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I try to run this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

I get the error: Failed to evaluate. Reason: Cannot evaluate because the thread is resumed.

I don't really know why this appears nor how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The error message appears to be produced by the debugger.

(Refer to line 70 of this: https://github.com/Microsoft/java-debug/blob/master/com.microsoft.java.debug.core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/java/debug/core/adapter/handler/EvaluateRequestHandler.java)

The preceding comment says:

```
// stackFrameReference is null means the stackframe is continued by user manually,
```

It seems that you may have gotten the debugger into a slightly confused state.  There was a related issue in the issue tracker for the Java debugger for Visual Studio.

- https://github.com/Microsoft/java-debug/issues/109

The evaluation has some hints as to what the developer thinks was going on.  Unfortunately, the person who raised the issue did not explain what he was doing, and the developer concluded that there was no real issue here.

But it is also possible that the underlying cause for this error message has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you change internalConsole to integratedTerminal or externalTerminal in launch.json works, but say bye bye colors

```
// "console": "internalConsole",
"console": "integratedTerminal",
//"console": "externalTerminal",
```

Answer (score 0):

> The default Debug Console in VS Code doesn't support inputs. In case your program need inputs from terminal, you can use Integrated Terminal within VS Code or external terminal to launch it.

(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging)

Open `~/.vscode/launch.json` and change `configurations.console` to `integratedTerminal` or `externalTerminal` (probably the former).

```
// launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)-App<test-app>",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // ..........
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            // **********
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "mainClass": "com.test.app.App",
            "projectName": "test-app",
            "args": ""
        }
    ]
}
```